# Joining multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with joining 2 tables together, as follows

```
Table 'jobs'
id int(20) auto_increment PK
name varchar(200)

Table 'logs'
id int(20) auto_increment PK
job_id int(20) FK(events.id)
event varchar(200)
```

I want all `unique ID's` that have a log entry for `logs.event = 'initialized'` AND `logs.event = 'failed'`

How can I do this with MySQL?

I've tried this query, but it won't work (Query succeeded, 0 results, while there are results that match in the DB)

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.name
FROM
jobs as a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN logs b ON b.job_id = a.id
WHERE
b.event = 'initialized'
AND
b.event = 'failed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.id, a.name
FROM jobs as a
INNER JOIN logs b ON b.job_id = a.id
INNER JOIN logs c ON c.job_id = a.id
WHERE
  b.event = 'initialized'
  AND
  c.event = 'failed'
```

Basically I'm assuming that any single log can't be both "initialised" AND "failed" at the same time - so you have to join twice and test two separate log entries... ?

Edit: update with suggestions in comments.

Comment: Ended up using this, but then with `INNER JOIN` instead of `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, since the load per query was 2.4 sec with `RIGHT OUTER` and 0.003 sec with `INNER` =|

Comment: you'll probably want to add a distinct to this, as it'll return duplicate rows

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.name
FROM jobs a
INNER JOIN logs b on b.jobid = a.id
WHERE
b.event = 'initialized'
AND a.id in (SELECT distinct jobid from logs WHERE event = 'failed')
```

Answer (score 1):

I will not attempt to give you a solution because I think there is nothing wrong with your query and should give the results if you say there are matching rows in your DB.

But a few points though:

1. Are you sure you want all Job IDs that have a log entry for BOTH "initialized" and "failed" events? Perhaps you are looking for all Job IDs that have a log entry for either "initialized" or "failed" events. If the latter is what you need, try using `OR` instead of `AND` in your WHERE clause.
2. According to your table structure `logs`.`job_id` is a FK for `events`.`id`. But in your query you are doing a join between `logs`.`job_id` and `jobs`.`id`. Is your FK incorrect or `logs`.`job_id` does not job Ids but event Ids?

On another note, why are you using a RIGHT OUTER JOIN? Does INNER JOIN not work for retrieving the same results?

Comment: I used `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` out of inexperience, `INNER JOIN` is what I should (and now am) using. I do have set the `logs.job_id` as foreign key to `jobs.id`.

Comment: @Sander: thanks for the clarification and it's nice that you are using INNER join; I just saw that you've already found your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to check for both events you should inner join JOBS table twice with LOGS (one join per event). I use inner join because you want both event's to have occured.

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.name
FROM
jobs as a
 INNER JOIN logs b ON b.job_id = a.id
 INNER JOIN logs c ON c.job_id = a.id
WHERE
b.event = 'initialized'
AND
c.event = 'failed'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.name
FROM
jobs a
INNER JOIN logs b ON  b.job_id = a.id AND b.event = 'initialized' AND b.event = 'failed'
GROUP BY a.id
```